# Car not staying warm in gear

Tags: cooling-system, chrysler, town-and-country

I have a crystler 2013 town and country van. I changed out the thermostat and flushed the coolant. It will start to heat up in park but when you put in gear to drive only maintains heat for 10 miles then the temp gauge will drop until it gets to c then a red l lightning bolt symbol will appear on dash and it only blows cold air. But if I put the car back bbn into park and shut it off and then turn back on and leave in park the car will heat back up. But once in drive it will cool back down and do all over again. Please help.

Comment: is the coolant level in the radiator filled,and are you sure the thermostat is the right one and installed correctly.you might want to get a readout of the error codes.

Comment: Is the electric fan on the radiator under the hood running all the time?  It should only come on when necessary?

Comment: Have you checked the coolant bypass valve? Might be stuck closed. The thermostat is supposed to act on it. A fairly large portion of coolant water should bypass the radiator, esp now in winter time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state once you put it in drive it cools down ... is this with or without driving the vehicle?

Comment: *'The lightning bolt on the dash means that there is a problem with the electronic throttle control system in your vehicle. Get a code reader and scan the engine for any logged codes. The light may be on for a glitch and the electronic throttle control system needs to be reset.'* ([source](https://www.yourmechanic.com/question/the-light-on-the-dash-is-coming-on-the-one-that-looks-like-a-red-lightning-volt-what-does-this-mean-by-patrick)) Check your vehicle's OBD-II error codes!